Can't install AnyDesk and Visual Studio Code on Orange Pi 3B
I have a task to setup an Orange Pi 3B and to install 2 simple programs (AnyDesk, Visual Studio Code).
I can't wrap my head around how to install programs.
I tried a trainload of meaningless (to me) commands in the console and I still can't install anything.
I tried the AnyDesk PPA and that that method didn't work.
snap install code resulted in:
snap: command not found

I tried installing snapd and running sudo snap install code and sudo snap install --classic code. I received this error:
snap "code" is not available on stable for this architecture (arm64) but exists on other architectures (amd64)

Looks like sudo apt install ./name worked, VS window opens. But i received
Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

When running anydesk
error while loading shared libraries: libpoolkit-gobject-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I already reinstalled anydesk via sudo apt remove anydesk and installed it back again via sudo apt install ./anydeskname sudo apt install --reinstall ./anydeskname didn't work either

What have you tried? What happens when you try it? Any error messages? Installing software is usually as simple as opening the App Center and searching for the software to be installed (GUI) or running a apt install <software-name> command. VSCode should be installed via snap (sudo snap install code), perhaps it's the same for AnyDesk.

Well turns out AnyDesk has a repo for .deb packages: http://deb.anydesk.com/howto.html

This question is similar to: How do I install applications in Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Starting with anydesk i tried to download armhf.deb and amd64.deb packages from the official site, the armhf.deb gave me a prompt to install but when i click it the "package installer" (or idk how it's named) just dissapears, amd64.deb installer gave me a "wrong architecturer amd64" error message, i ran an addarchitecture command and now it gives me "dependency is not satisfiable:libc6 (>=2.7)" error.

Yesterday i stumbled upon the same anydesk repo guide, did what it said< and anydesk installed, BUT when i try to launch it from the applications menu it does nothing :(

Your Pis are ARM-based, as far as VSCode and AnyDesk are concerned there's no reason to add foreign architectures, both have native ARM packages, I don't know what's the deal with the AnyDesk (ARM) .deb package, but you can try installing from the PPA I linked. You can add the PPA by following the instructions on the same page. As far as VSCode is concerned, try sudo snap install code (or sudo snap install --classic code)

(AnyDesk automatically launches and sits in the top-right corner IIRC, perhaps it's there and you didn't notice? Otherwise try the PPA method, uninstalling the package you installed first)

This repo sadly doesn't have a software center. About the VS code, i downloaded the amd64.deb files from the official site and it gave me anothe dependency error "libasound2". I tried installing everithing via the console but it can't find the packages

Please edit your question 1. Explaining that you tried the AnyDesk PPA and that that method didn't work 2. Adding the output of sudo snap install --classic code, so that we can look at it.

Anydesk is launching as i said and does literally nothing, just like the installer. About VS Code, i can't install it via the terminal as i said 'apt install' code can't locate the package, 'snap install code' snap: command not found, 'apt install --classic code' --classic is not understood in combination

snap: command not found is weird. What happens if you run sudo apt install snapd? Can you then install VSCode via sudo snap install --classic code?

Please don't post any output of those commands as a comment; edit your question insted once you've tried that

For VSCode, try cd Downloads (or cd to wherever the ARM version of the .deb file is) and try to run sudo apt install ./name-of-the-arm-version-of-the-deb-file.deb

The error message while installing VSCode is ok, it doesn't matter. Onto AnyDesk: try and run anydesk from the command line, see if it throws some error message and if it does please add it to the question.

Ok, try and do (almost) the same for AnyDesk: cd to where the (ARM) .deb installer is and run  sudo apt install --reinstall ./name-of-the-arm-version-of-the-deb-file.deb

Any more help? @kos

Try sudo apt install libpolkit-gobject-1-0
